# Memory consumption of NumPy function for standard deviation

Tags: python, numpy, memory, scipy

I'm currently using the Python bindings of GDAL to work on quite large raster data sets (> 4 GB). Since loading them into memory at once is no feasible solution for me I read them into smaller blocks and do the computations piece by piece. To avoid a new allocation for every block read I'm using the `buf_obj` argument ([here](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal_array-module.html#BandReadAsArray)) to read the values into an preallocated NumPy array. At one point I have to compute the mean and standard deviation of the entire raster. Naturally I've used `np.std` for the computation. However by profiling the memory consumption of my program I realized that with each invocation of `np.std` additionally memory is allocated and released.

A minimum working example which demonstrates this behavior:

```
In [1]  import numpy as np
In [2]  a = np.random.rand(20e6)  # Approx. 150 MiB of memory
In [3]  %memit np.mean(a)
peak memory: 187.30 MiB, increment: 0.48 MiB
In [4]  %memit np.std(a)
peak memory: 340.24 MiB, increment: 152.91 MiB
```

A search within the source tree of NumPy on GitHub revealed that the `np.std` function internally invokes the `_var` function from `_methods.py` ([here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/_methods.py)). At one point `_var` computes the deviations from the mean and sums them up.  Therefore an temporary copy of the input array is created. The function essentially computes the standard deviation as follows:

```
mu = sum(arr) / len(arr)
tmp = arr - mu
tmp = tmp * tmp
sd = np.sum(tmp) / len(arr)
```

While this approach is OK for smaller input arrays it's definitely no way to go for larger ones. Since I'm using smaller blocks of memory as mentioned before this additional copy is not an game-breaking issue from the memory point of view in my program. However what bugs me is that for each block a new allocation is made and released before reading the next block.

Is there some other function within NumPy or SciPy which utilizes an aproach with constant memory consumption like the Welford algorithm ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm)) for one pass computation of the mean and standard deviation?

Another way to go would be to implement a custom version of the `_var` function with an optional `out` argument for a preallocated buffer (like NumPy ufuncs). With this approach the additional copy would not be eliminated but at least the memory consumption would be constant and runtime for the allocations in each block is saved.

**EDIT:** Tested the Cython implementation of the Welford algorithm as suggested by kezzos.

Cython implementation (modified from kezzos):

```
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np
from libc.math cimport sqrt

@cython.boundscheck(False)
def iterative_approach(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] a):
    cdef long n = 0
    cdef float mean = 0
    cdef float M2 = 0
    cdef long i
    cdef float delta
    cdef float a_min = 10000000  # Must be set to Inf and -Inf for real cases
    cdef float a_max = -10000000
    for i in range(len(a)):
        n += 1
        delta = a[i] - mean
        mean += delta / n
        M2 += delta * (a[i] - mean)
        if a[i] < a_min:
            a_min = a[i]
        if a[i] > a_max:
            a_max = a[i]
    return a_min, a_max, mean, sqrt(M2 / (n - 1))
```

NumPy implementation (mean and std can possibly be computed in one function):

```
def vector_approach(a):
    return np.min(a), np.max(a), np.mean(a), np.std(a, ddof=1)
```

Test results using a random data set (times in milliseconds, best of 25):

```
----------------------------------
| Size |  Iterative |     Vector |
----------------------------------
|  1e2 |    0.00529 |    0.17149 |
|  1e3 |    0.02027 |    0.16856 |
|  1e4 |    0.17850 |    0.23069 |
|  1e5 |    1.93980 |    0.77727 |
|  1e6 |   18.78207 |    8.83245 |
|  1e7 |  180.04069 |  101.14722 |
|  1e8 | 1789.60228 | 1086.66737 |
----------------------------------
```

It seems like the iterative approach using Cython is faster with smaller data sets and the NumPy vector (possibly SIMD accelerated) approach for larger data sets with 10000+ elements. All tests were conducted with Python 2.7.9 and NumPy version 1.9.2.

Note that in the real case to upper functions would be used to compute the statistics for a single block of the raster. The standard deviations and means for all block are to be combined with methodology suggested in Wikipedia ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Combining_standard_deviations)). It has the advantage that not all elements of the raster need to be summed up and thereby avoids the float overflow problem (at least to some point).

Comment: Have you tried using the Welford algorithm (in pure python) on the buffer object?

Comment: @kezzos I've updated the question with test results for a pure Python implementation. The Python implementation is significantly slower than the NumPy version.

Answer (score 6):

I doubt you will find any such functions in `numpy`. The raison d'être of `numpy` is that it takes advantage of [vector processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_processor) instruction sets -- performing the same instruction of large amounts of data. Basically `numpy` trades memory efficiency for speed efficiency. However, due to the memory intensive nature of Python, `numpy` is also able to achieve certain memory efficiencies by associating the data type with the array as a whole and not each individual element.

One way to improve the speed, but still sacrifice some memory overhead is calculate the standard deviation in chunks eg.

```
import numpy as np

def std(arr, blocksize=1000000):
    """Written for py3, change range to xrange for py2.
    This implementation requires the entire array in memory, but it shows how you can
    calculate the standard deviation in a piecemeal way.
    """
    num_blocks, remainder = divmod(len(arr), blocksize)
    mean = arr.mean()
    tmp = np.empty(blocksize, dtype=float)
    total_squares = 0
    for start in range(0, blocksize*num_blocks, blocksize):
        # get a view of the data we want -- views do not "own" the data they point to
        # -- they have minimal memory overhead
        view = arr[start:start+blocksize]
        # # inplace operations prevent a new array from being created
        np.subtract(view, mean, out=tmp)
        tmp *= tmp
        total_squares += tmp.sum()
    if remainder:
        # len(arr) % blocksize != 0 and need process last part of array
        # create copy of view, with the smallest amount of new memory allocation possible
        # -- one more array *view*
        view = arr[-remainder:]
        tmp = tmp[-remainder:]
        np.subtract(view, mean, out=tmp)
        tmp *= tmp
        total_squares += tmp.sum()
        
    var = total_squares / len(arr)
    sd = var ** 0.5
    return sd

a = np.arange(20e6)
assert np.isclose(np.std(a), std(a))
```

Showing the speed up --- the larger the `blocksize`, the larger the speed up. And considerably lower memory overhead. Not entirely the lower memory overhead is 100% accurate.

```
In [70]: %timeit np.std(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 105 ms per loop

In [71]: %timeit std(a, blocksize=4096)
10 loops, best of 3: 160 ms per loop

In [72]: %timeit std(a, blocksize=1000000)
10 loops, best of 3: 105 ms per loop

In [75]: %memit np.std(a)
peak memory: 512.70 MiB, increment: 152.59 MiB

In [73]: %memit std(a, blocksize=4096)
peak memory: 360.11 MiB, increment: 0.00 MiB

In [74]: %memit std(a, blocksize=1000000)
peak memory: 360.11 MiB, increment: 0.00 MiB
```

Comment: Actually, for a long time, SIMD (vector) instructions where only used by Numpy in calls to BLAS / LAPACK functions (depending on the back-end). Only since v1.6 there's actual SSE code in Numpy, for `einsum`. And only since v1.8 basic math operations are accelerated.

Comment: @Dunes Actually I'm using this approach already since I'm computing the standard deviation blockwise for the entire raster. However I'm using the natural block size suggested by the GDAL driver of the data set. Which is typically one image row at a time. Your way of implementing the standard deviation function by myself seems to be the way to go since therby I can avoid the extra allocation for each block by using a constant preallocated buffer (`tmp` in your example).

Comment: @moarningsun Thanks for the hint. I assumed NumPy would use at least the SIMD instructions of SSE2 for a longer time. Especially the computation of the standard deviation (subtraction, multiplication and summation) should be nicely accelerated.

Answer (score 5):

Cython to the rescue! This achieves a nice speed up:

```python
%%cython
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np
from libc.math cimport sqrt

@cython.boundscheck(False)
def std_welford(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] a):
    cdef int n = 0
    cdef float mean = 0
    cdef float M2 = 0
    cdef int a_len = len(a)
    cdef int i
    cdef float delta
    cdef float result
    for i in range(a_len):
        n += 1
        delta = a[i] - mean
        mean += delta / n
        M2 += delta * (a[i] - mean)
    if n < 2:
        result = np.nan
        return result
    else:
        result = sqrt(M2 / (n - 1))
        return result
```

Using this to test:

```
a = np.random.rand(10000).astype(np.float)
print std_welford(a)
%timeit -n 10 -r 10 std_welford(a)
```

**Cython code**

```
0.288327455521
10 loops, best of 10: 59.6 µs per loop
```

**Original code**

```
0.289605617397
10 loops, best of 10: 18.5 ms per loop
```

**Numpy std**

```
0.289493223504
10 loops, best of 10: 29.3 µs per loop
```

So a speed increase of around 300x. Still not as good as the numpy version..

Comment: Now your test data and temporaries still fit inside the CPU cache. I think you will see Numpy performing worse relative to your Cython function as the input array grows bigger.

Comment: When I try the welford algorithm as implemented above I get significantly different results than I do from `np.std`. Given `arr = np.arange(10, dtype=float)`, then `std_welford(arr) == 3.02...`, but `np.std(arr) == 2.87...`

Comment: @Dunes, just a matter of definition. Try `np.std(arr, ddof=1)`

Comment: @moarningsun Thanks  I knew I was missing something. My stats is a bit rusty.

Comment: @kezzos I've updated the question with test results. It shows there is a dependency on the size of the array. With smaller arrays your implementation is faster while with larger arrays NumPy is faster despite the fact that all NumPy functions together are iterating the array multiple times. But the acceleration due the SIMD instruction sets seems to outweigh this factor.